# Open Excel workbook from Word in same folder and copy paste some cells

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to open an Excel Workbook from a macro in Word. The Excel Workbook and the Word Document are placed in the same folder.

After opening the workbook it should copy a range and special paste it at the cursor in the word document and do some editing on the table.

The latter part I think I can do, but the first part says "Run-time error '424': Object recquired

I am not expert and cannot get this to work.

Thanks in advance!

I have searched and found the below code, which people have been upvoting, but for some reason it does not work for me.

```
    Sub Code()

    Workbooks.Open (ActiveDocument.Path & ".\source.xlsx")

    'Copy some cells and paste them into Selected place in word

    End Sub
```

Comment: Delete the leading . In '.\source.xlsx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instance the excel , them open it , and them copy the range you want , after that u can paste on your selection

The code below will help you to understand how to do it , but you will need to change some values from Range and Locations to place the Paste.

```
Sub Code()
    Dim exc As Object
    Dim wb As Object

    Set exc = CreateObject("excel.application")
    Set wb = exc.workbooks.Open(ActiveDocument.Path & ".\source.xlsx")
    With wb
        .sheets(1).Range("A1:B3").Copy
    End With

    Application.Selection.Paste


End Sub
```